# How to extract program code from ISO file

Tags: data-mining, disk

In the Xbox 360 game *Project Sylpheed: Arc of Deception.* There are secret sub objectives for each level. On stage 11 "Flaming Clouds" there are 4, I have found two sources claiming they know each of them, but is actually untrue. One is still hidden. This is a very unpopular game, and no one has investigated it, and I want to know what it is. I have a disk image file of the game (ISO file). How would I go about finding the level trigger for the sub objective? I have already attempted to extract the 7gb iso using 7zip and Winrar, but each yielded the same 12mb files that contain nothing relevant what so ever. Obviously the core of the information is hidden and remains unextracted. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

https://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/ or linux/mac mount -o loop /path/to/my-iso-image.iso /mnt/iso

from there you're going to need a reverse compiler probabably but I don't know what your game is written in. You might luck out and find the levels coded in lua or something though.

Something else that can be happening is 7zip is actually opening the iso right, and the 12mb could be instructions to go download the actual game code from somewhere else. That sometimes happens with consoles.

Comment: Thank you. the 'useless information" is actually video files of xbox loading screens. i checked again, none of them are instructions. besides that, i will investigate this path.